# Qt Creator cross-compile from Linux (x86_64) to Raspbian (arm)

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I've spent some time looking for a simple guide to compile for raspbian (arm) from Linux (x86_64), using Qt Creator.  I assumed that all I needed to do was setup a kit (gcc options etc) but every guide seems to go in a different direction.

Most guides want me to install Qt Creator or compilation tools on the raspberry. Not what I want. I should point out that there is a Github project which compiles various versions of the Qt libraries for Rasbian. My plan was to load the needed libraries that way.  I just want to create the executable in Linux, and copy it to the Pi.

Is there something wrong with my expectations? Should this be simple matter of creating the right kit? Is there such a guide?